# How to save multiple data in localStorage with zustand?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend, zustand

I build a stepper and I want save my data in each step and access all my last data`s

```
    export const useInformation = create(
  persist(
    (set) => ({
      personInfo: [],
      setPersonInfo: (callBack) => {
        set((state) => ({
          personInfo: callBack,
        }));
      },
    }),
    {
      name: 'Person_setting',
      getStorage: () => localStorage,
    }
  )
);
```

this my store with zustand and it will update in my component with onclick but when i update it, its return just last data steps

but

Comment: We need to see the **RELEVANT** code for any issues you're having. How's your Zustand store set up, how are you updating it from the component, are there any relevant bits of data we need? And so on. There's no way we can help you given the 2 vague sentences you've posted

Comment: this is my first question on stackoverflow and i just learned how to use...
yes i edit my question and explain how to store my zustand and updates